Enharmonic equivalence for single, double, triple and quadruple accidentals
Examples for enharmonic equivalence for single and double accidentals can be easily found (ex. C --> B#, Dbb; C# --> B##, Db). But what about the full list of possible options up to 4 accidentals? Could you please provide an enharmonic scale that have triple and quadruple accidentals? I believe it must have less then 7 notes like pentatonic scale. Also I am interested in rules of how to convert a scale with any numbers of notes (at least 5-8) to enharmonic equivalent

The 'standard' scale has 7 notes before hitting the root octave. That would be s good place to start. Using pentatonic or worse still blues scales, it'll complicate things. But, why would anyone in their right mind want any scale with even double sharps/flats?? It seems a pointless exercise, with no advantage to anyone , except from an academic pov.

Yes, I am working on a js library that will be used for theory rather than practical usage. So I need all the cases theoretically possible even if they are pointless for musician. I know that up to 4 accidentals are possible, so I'd like to have a requested table. But considering that I'm not familiar with theory well, I am asking for help. Obviously I can generate such a list knowing what # and b means, but I will not be sure if it will be correct from theory perspective of view. So, maybe it worth starting from this

@Vitone In principle, an unlimited number of accidentals is possible. It's just that the likelihood of running into such a note in the wild rapidly falls to zero. Cxxxxxx is a perfectly valid note, enharmonically equivalent to C (the twelve sharps raise the tone by a full octave), but you won't see it anywhere except as a joke.

“up to 4 accidentals are possible”: If you’re not constrained by practical considerations, and are indulging a purely theoretical exercise, why stop at four? there’s no special arbitrary significance to four. Theoretically, one could apply an infinite number of accidentals. But practical considerations almost always limit it to doubles and make those pretty rare. So… 1) why abandon practicality at all, and 2) if you’re doing so, why pick an arbitrary constraint? (I’m not saying you should go beyond 4 because I don’t think you should go beyond 2… just saying.)

This restriction of 4 accidentals max because of such restrictions in other js library used in a project. But you a right. It can be parameterized and enharmonic equivalents can be generated for a given number of accidentals. Anyway my original question is still actual since I am going to cover my code with tests and I need correct data to make sure everything works correctly. @Divzna, that's the reason why I am asking in this channel. I can write a program but I cannot be sure it works correct without theoretical knowledge.

I don’t understand. If you’re aware that four accidentals is an arbitrary restriction why not instead choose two accidentals as the arbitrary restriction and save yourself a lot of needless effort? What benefit is there from even thinking about or coding for triple and quadruple accidentals? If you don’t care about musicians don’t even use accidentals, just 12 pitch classes numbered 0 to 11.

Can you explain what you mean by this: “Also I am interested in rules of how to convert a scale with any numbers of notes (at least 5-8) to enharmonic equivalent”. I’ve never heard of “converting” scales to enharmonic equivalents. Maybe if you give one example we can explain how it works. Regarding “ I will not be sure if it will be correct from theory perspective of view.” I would say considering more than two accidentals is incorrect from a theory point of view. I’ve taken tons of theory classes and read tons of books and web sites on theory and never heard of accidentals beyond doubles.

"So I need all the cases theoretically possible": in that case, you should probably write a function to calculate them as needed rather than have a lookup table.

@ToddWilcox I can think of two ways to convert a scale to an enharmonic equivalent: one is to replace only some elements of the scale with an enharmonic equivalent (e.g. a C major scale but with E# where F should be). The resulting scale is arguably enharmonically different because the relationships between scale elements are different (e.g. augmented third rather than perfect fourth). The more rigorous way would be to apply the same enharmonic operation to each element of the scale (e.g. convert the C major scale to the B# major scale by lowering each element by a diminished second).

One thing to keep in mind is that because of the 7 letter/12 note system no note will be represented by all 4 sharp or flat accidentals. For example, C can only be B#, A###, Dbb or Ebbbb. There is no 2 or 4 sharp representation nor a 1 or 3 flat representation.

@phoog Yes, that makes sense. My question is whether one or the other of those is what the asker is asking about or are they asking about something else, and I feel it’s important to know because why would you do either of those things? The answer to why would definitely affect my answer to how.

@ToddWilcox I had that question, too, but couldn't fit it into the comment above. Looking at this as a programming problem, the question "why do you want to know" is even more on point; presumably this table is sought to perform some part of some other calculation, in which case this is probably an example of what's known on Stack Overflow as an X/Y problem: asking about a lower-level problem when the real problem is at another level of abstraction (e.g. "what kind of violin string should I use" when the real problem is that the instrument isn't holding its tune because the peg is slipping).

I created a new tag "music-app-programming", because this is clearly about that and there are many, many questions that could be tagged with the tag. Feel free to comment and disagree on it.

If you know how accidentals work, then that's everything you need to solve this on your own. If for any reason you need to put together a full list, just sit and write it. I'm not going to do all the trivial and tedious work for you.
Here's a hint, though. If you're working with the standard 12 semitones, then your list will obviously include 12 notes: C and its equivalents; C# and its equivalents; D and its equivalents; and so on up to B and its equivalents.
Place all naturals on the right lines of your table, then all single sharps, then all double sharps, and so on, until you include all the quadruple flats, and viola, I mean voilà, there's your full list. Format it in any way that you deem easy to read.

@Divzna thank you, maybe you are right and it's better to generate such a table rather hardcoding

@Vitone Depends what exactly you need it for. In your question you didn't mention anything about programming, so I assumed you wanted a reference you could look up whenever with your eyes. For a program, it tends to be a better idea to just set a value for it to read than have it make the exact same calculation over and over again every time. On the other hand, if you wanted it to handle everything that's theoretically possible without an arbitrary cutoff, then that's infinite, so you would have to go with some kind of algorithm rather than just an array of fixed values.

In any case, if you need to discuss programming, you're in the wrong channel.

Thank you for your responses.
Here's my generated by a program answer for max number of accidentals = 4:
C: Dbb, Ebbbb, A###, B#
C#: Db, Ebbb, Fbbbb, A####, B##
D: C##, Ebb, Fbbb, B###
D#: C###, Eb, Fbb, Gbbbb, B####
E: C####, D##, Fb, Gbbb
F: D###, E#, Gbb, Abbbb
F#: D####, E##, Gb, Abbb
G: E###, F##, Abb, Bbbbb
G#: Cbbbb, E####, F###, Ab, Bbbb
A: Cbbb, F####, G##, Bbb
A#: Cbb, Dbbbb, G###, Bb
B: Cb, Dbbb, G####, A##


Unless I've overlooked something, it seems right.

remember that those are all the enharmonic equivalents excluding the note they were generated from (future viewers, avoid copy paste errors in some applications perhaps)

Pitch Class
There is a music theory concept called pitch class. On a piano there are seven different pitches called "C", but they are all of the same pitch class. All notes called C# belong to the same pitch class.
Often numeric values are substituted for letter names. For example C# = 1, Db = 1, B## = 1, Ebbb = 1, etc.... But by using numbers, there's no confusion over enharmonic naming.
Using this system, we have

    C: 0
C#/Db: 1
    D: 2
D#/Eb: 3
    E: 4
    F: 5
F#/Gb: 6
    G: 7
G#/Ab: 8
    A: 9
A#/Bb: 10
    B: 11

Calculating Pitch Class
Observe that the effect of a sharp is to add 1 to the letter-name value, and flats subtract 1 from the letter name value. Thus, C = 0 and C# = 1, and D = 2 and Db = 1. Since both C# = 1 and Db = 1, we know they are enharmonically equivalent. Further, consider E = 4. Including three flats, Ebbb, subtracts 3 from the "E" start value. So Ebbb = 1 as well.
Comparing Two Notes for Enharmonic Equivalence
This can easily be turned into an algorithm to calculate whether two notes are enharmonically equivalent.


; True is note1 and note2 are enharmonically equivalent
; False otherwise.

Function Enharmonic? (note1, note2) {

  Return ( (LetterValue(note1) + AccidentalAdjust(note1)) mod 12
           == (LetterValue(note2) + AccidentalAdjust(note2)) mod 12 )

}

; LetterValue strips out just the letter name from a note
;   and returns it's corresponding pitch class number.

; AccidentalAdjust counts the number of accidentals
;   and returns a positive number for sharps, negative for flats,
;   and zero for for naturals.

Scales
A scale is a series of steps, intervals, which also can be represented as numbers. The C major scale (C D E F G A B) can be thought of as starting from C, then moving by whole-step whole-step half-step whole-step whole-step whole-step half-step).

C + whole step
D + whole step
E + half step
F + whole step
G + whole step
A + whole step
B + half step (to return to C)

Now thinking in terms of pitch class numbers, the C major scale becomes 0 2 4 5 7 9 11, and we can see that whole-steps are like adding (or subtracting) 2, while half-steps are like adding (or subtracting 1).

C: 0 + 2 (whole)
D: 2 + 2 (whole)
E: 4 + 1 (half)
F: 5 + 2 (whole)
G: 7 + 2 (whole)
A: 9 + 2 (whole)
B: 11 + 1 (half — to return to C)

All those additions form an interval vector — a series of intervals generating the "next" pitch. The interval vector for the C major scale (for all major scales) is <2 2 1 2 2 2 1>.
Generating Scales
Since any scale can be defined by an interval vector, then creating enharmonically equivalent scales is again a simple algorithm. Except...
Except that diatonic scales, in particular, come with a naming convention: Every letter name must be used exactly one time. But this turns out to be a fairly minor complication.

Pick a starting pitch class number.
Get the interval vector representing the scale.
Choose a letter-based name for the starting pitch class number.
For each "next" note, add the appropriate interval value to the current note value, then calculate the sharps/flats needed to accompany the needed letter name.

Example

Starting pitch class number is 0 (i.e., C).
Interval vector is <2 2 1 2 2 2 1> (i.e., major).
Starting letter name = Dbb (i.e., pc 2 - 2 = 0 = C).
Next pitch is 0 + 2 = 2, and letter name must be "E"-based. E = 4, so we need two flats to get the right pitch class number. Next is 2 + 2 = 4, and the base letter is F = 5, so Fb is the third pitch.

Ultimately this will generate a Dbb major scale:

Dbb Ebb Fb Gbb Abb Bbb Cb
0   2   4  5   7   9   11
 +2  +2  +1 +2  +2  +2   +1
  W   W   H  W   W   W    H
C   D   E  F   G   A   B


A more generalized approach to scale construction would be to identify the intervals in the scale using the ordinal-plus-quality system.  For diatonic scales, this is equivalent to saying that every letter must occur exactly once, because a diatonic scale comprises only seconds (of which five are major and two are minor, of course).

An alternative simple solution path: you know that there are 7 note names. If you know those 7 major scales, you can just add/subtract a sharp to each note of the scale until you get to quadruple accidentals (technically, there's no reason to stop at 4 either).
That demonstrates the 7-sharp difference (think key sigs: C to C# is 7-0 = 7) you get from moving the root note up a half step.
For enharmonic equivalence, the magic number is 12 sharps (Gb->F# is 6-(-6) = 12). You have to know what order to add the sharps, but that's the same order they get added in usually just wrapping around modulo 7.
I've been writing this from the perspective of major scales, but any other scale would be done the same way, you just might have to deal with certain note names being included twice or not at all. An octatonic (HW dimished for example) scale on G is G Ab Bb Cb Db Ebb Fb F (I am picking this spelling. There are 8 notes and they have to be doubled somewhere. Fight me). If we wanted to find the Gb HW octatonic, all we have to do is subtract 7 sharps (add 7 flats): Gb Abb Bbb Cbb Dbb Ebbb Fbb Fb. If you want to use a <7 note scale, you can just do the math as though it were the major scale and then remove/adjust according to what the difference between it and the major scale was.
